# Using redis and elasticsearch concurrently, but it errors with "availableProcessors is already set to [4], rejecting [4]"

Tags: spring-boot, elasticsearch, redis

```
 ERROR:Factory method 'elasticsearchClient' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: availableProcessors is already set to [4], rejecting [4]
```

I just want to use redis and elasticsearch concurrently.

pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <!-- elasticsearch:5.6.10-->
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.4.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

and

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-redis</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.4.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

It is ok when I am just using redis or just using elasticsearch, but it errors if I use both. The errors:

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2018-09-04 20:23:34.284 ERROR 99054 --- [  restartedMain] org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.reportFailure[845] : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'controller_StudentEs': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'studentEsService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'studentEsService': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'elasticsearchTemplate' while setting bean property 'elasticsearchOperations'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'elasticsearchTemplate' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/elasticsearch/ElasticsearchDataAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'elasticsearchTemplate' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'elasticsearchClient' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/elasticsearch/ElasticsearchAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClient]: Factory method 'elasticsearchClient' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: availableProcessors is already set to [4], rejecting [4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:586)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:91)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:372)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1341)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:572)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:495)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:759)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:869)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:762)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:398)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:330)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1258)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1246)
    at com.example.demo.SpringBootTestApplication.main(SpringBootTestApplication.java:26)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'studentEsService': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'elasticsearchTemplate' while setting bean property 'elasticsearchOperations'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'elasticsearchTemplate' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/elasticsearch/ElasticsearchDataAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'elasticsearchTemplate' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'elasticsearchClient' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/elasticsearch/ElasticsearchAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClient]: Factory method 'elasticsearchClient' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: availableProcessors is already set to [4], rejecting [4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:378)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:110)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1602)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1354)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:572)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:495)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:251)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1135)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1062)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:583)
    ... 24 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'elasticsearchTemplate' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/elasticsearch/ElasticsearchDataAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'elasticsearchTemplate' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'elasticsearchClient' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/elasticsearch/ElasticsearchAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClient]: Factory method 'elasticsearchClient' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: availableProcessors is already set to [4], rejecting [4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:732)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:474)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1247)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1096)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:535)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:495)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:367)
    ... 37 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'elasticsearchClient' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/elasticsearch/ElasticsearchAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClient]: Factory method 'elasticsearchClient' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: availableProcessors is already set to [4], rejecting [4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:590)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1247)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1096)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:535)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:495)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:251)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1135)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1062)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:818)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:724)
    ... 47 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClient]: Factory method 'elasticsearchClient' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: availableProcessors is already set to [4], rejecting [4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:582)
    ... 60 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: availableProcessors is already set to [4], rejecting [4]
    at io.netty.util.NettyRuntime$AvailableProcessorsHolder.setAvailableProcessors(NettyRuntime.java:51)
    at io.netty.util.NettyRuntime.setAvailableProcessors(NettyRuntime.java:87)
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty4.Netty4Utils.setAvailableProcessors(Netty4Utils.java:85)
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty4.Netty4Transport.<init>(Netty4Transport.java:140)
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.Netty4Plugin.lambda$getTransports$0(Netty4Plugin.java:93)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClient.buildTemplate(TransportClient.java:177)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClient.<init>(TransportClient.java:257)
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.client.TransportClientFactoryBean$SpringDataTransportClient.<init>(TransportClientFactoryBean.java:234)
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.client.TransportClientFactoryBean.buildClient(TransportClientFactoryBean.java:103)
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.client.TransportClientFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(TransportClientFactoryBean.java:98)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchAutoConfiguration.elasticsearchClient(ElasticsearchAutoConfiguration.java:59)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$c8e76722.CGLIB$elasticsearchClient$0(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$c8e76722$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$964b94ce.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:361)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$c8e76722.elasticsearchClient(<generated>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154)
    ... 61 common frames omitted

Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:56697', transport: 'socket'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I am trying to fix it by commenting out:

```
//    @Autowired
//    private StringRedisTemplate redisTemplate;
```

That works, but then I can not use the redis function.
What is correct method to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

In the SpringBootTestApplication.class file, use:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    System.setProperty("es.set.netty.runtime.available.processors", "false");
    SpringApplication.run(SpringBootTestApplication.class, args);
    }
```